# trouble in obtaining sum of values after checking rows and columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have some trouble trying to get the values of the first column with EG and 0 adding up the values found at column H, EG and 0. The sum will be placed at Column O row 3.

I have tried to write out the code, to find the Name, EG and also the temp, 0. Unfortunately, the code looks for the last 0 seen at column O. If you have any idea, do share yours, will appreciate your help! THanks!

[image]

```
  Sub Macro1()

   Dim LastRow1 As Long, RowG As Range, RowCheck As Long, Rowtosave As Long, LastCol1 As Long
   Dim EGCheck As Long, ColEG As Range, firstEG As Long, IGCheck As Long, ColIG As Range
   Dim findtemp As Range, tempRow As Long, tempRow1 As Long, lastEG As Long
   Dim totalvalue As Long, valuestoadd As Long, tempCheck As Long
   Dim emptycol As Long, empty1 As Range, Colempty As Long, tempcol As Long

    LastRow1 = 50
    LastCol1 = 50

      For RowCheck = 1 To LastRow1

          With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCheck, 1)
              If .Value = "Name" Then

                   Rowtosave = RowCheck

                 For EGCheck = 1 To LastCol1

                    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rowtosave, EGCheck)

                    If .Value = "EG" Then

                     firstEG = EGCheck

                    End If
                    End With

                Next EGCheck

               For IGCheck = 1 To LastCol1

                    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rowtosave, IGCheck)

                    If .Value = "IG" Then

                    lastEG = IGCheck - 1

                    End If
                    End With

              Next IGCheck

         End If

       End With

    Next RowCheck

   'Look for temp

   totalvalue = 0

    For RowCheck = 1 To LastRow1

       With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCheck, 1)
         If .Value = "temp" Then

          tempRow1 = RowCheck

              For tempCheck = 1 To lastEG

              With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(tempRow1, tempCheck)

               If .Value = "0" Then

                  tempcol = tempCheck

                valuestoadd = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(tempRow1, tempcol).Select

                totalvalue = totalvalue + valuestoadd

              End If
             End With

              Next tempCheck

          End If
          End With

      Next RowCheck

   'Look for empty column
      emptycol = 1

      Do

     Set empty1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(tempRow1, emptycol)

       If empty1 = "" Then

        emptycol = emptycol + 1

        Colempty = emptycol

       empty1 = totalvalue

      End If
     Exit Do

    emptycol = emptycol + 1

    Loop

  End Sub
```

**Follow up:**

What my code needs to do is as follows:

1. Check Row for "Name".
2. After finding "Name" will look for "EG" and set it to first "EG"
3. Then it will try to look for first "IG" so that we can have the last of the first"EG" (note: "EG"  groups Column B-D, IG group Column E to G, 2nd EG group H-J and so on.
4. After that, look for temp.
5. Then find 0 or 100 or overall which will be within the column from for example "EG"'s category, "First EG" TO "Last of the first EG".
6. Then add 1 to Row so that we can tabulate the sum of test1.
7. Get the sum of 0 from "First EG(Column B)" and "Second EG(Column H)" and place it at an empty column say Column O. For this example, the resultant will be 2+ 0 = 2

I realized the confusion caused when i use lastEG. What i meant for lastEG was last of first EG

I hope this clear up the doubts.

**Discussion with Tony and follow up on improving the question**

- There is a row with "Name" in column A. Call this the Name row. It may not necessary be on the first row.
- Within the Name row, there are cells containing "EG". A few cells after a cell containg "EG" is a cell containing "IG". Call an range starting at a cell containing "EG" and continuing to (but not including) the next cell containing "IG", an EG range. In the example, the EG ranges are B:D and H:J.
- There is a row with "temp" in column A. Call this the Temp row. In the example, the Temp row is immediately under the Name row but apparently this is not a requirement. The Name and Temp rows can appear anywhere within the Sheet and Name will always be above temp but that does not means they are paired together, some times we can have name, month, temp.
- There is a row with "test1" in column A. Call this the Test1 row.
- In the example, the Test1 Row is immediately under the Temp row. The code does not access the Test1 row. The explanation says that the row under the Temp row is the Test1 row but this is not checked.
- Within each EG range within the Temp row, there is a cell containing '0', '100' and 'Overall'. The cell below the zero will be empty or contain a number. The value of those numbers for all EG ranges is to be totalled. This total is to be saved in the cell after the first empty cell below the temp row, for example, O3 - Q3 where values will be placed at.

I hope this gets better and Tony, I have used some of your points and edited it.

Comment: If you're looping to find a value, then you probably want to use `Exit For` once you find what you're looking for.  I tried to follow your requirements but they could be a bit clearer...

Comment: @TimWilliams, i have tried, with the exit For, i'm not very sure which to have it? where do u suggest it should be at?

Comment: First thing to do is update your question with a very detailed explanation of exactly what you want your code to do.

Comment: @TimWilliams, i have updated my questions with follow up:, hope it will make things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected the most obvious errors in your code but it makes little sense to me so I cannot tell if it does what you want.

```
' Option Explicit ensures that misspelt names are
' not taken as an implicit declaration
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()

  ' This is legal syntax but I find it confusing.  I only have two or more
  ' variables in a Dim if they are closely related.
  Dim LastRow1 As Long, RowG As Range, RowCheck As Long, Rowtosave As Long, LastCol1 As Long
  Dim EGCheck As Long, ColEG As Range, firstEG As Long, IGCheck As Long, ColIG As Range
  Dim findtemp As Range, tempRow As Long, tempRow1 As Long, lastEG As Long
  Dim totalvalue As Long, valuestoadd As Long, tempCheck As Long
  Dim emptycol As Long, empty1 As Range, Colempty As Long, tempcol As Long

  ' You can nest Withs.
  ' You only use one worksheet so let us declare that at the top.

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' These statements will have to be replaced when the number of rows and
    ' columns exceed 50.
    'LastRow1 = 50
    'LastCol1 = 50

    LastRow1 = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastCol1 = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    Rowtosave = 0   ' Initialise in case not found
    For RowCheck = 1 To LastRow1
      ' I use: With .Cells(R, C)
      '          .Value = 5
      '          .NumberFormat = "0.00"
      '          .Font.Bold = True
      '        End With
      ' because I want to refer to .Cells(R, C) in several ways.
      ' I do not see the benefit of:
      '   With .Cells(R, C)
      '     .Value = 5
      '   End With
      If .Cells(RowCheck, 1).Value = "Name" Then
        Rowtosave = RowCheck
        firstEG = 0     ' Initialise so you can test for
        lastEG = 0      ' EG and IG not being found.
        For EGCheck = 1 To LastCol1
          If .Cells(Rowtosave, EGCheck).Value = "EG" Then
            firstEG = EGCheck
            ' Without the Exit For, the search will continue and
            ' firstEG will identify the last EG not the first.
            Exit For
          End If
        Next EGCheck
        For IGCheck = 1 To LastCol1
          If .Cells(Rowtosave, IGCheck).Value = "IG" Then
            ' I find the name lastEG confusing
            lastEG = IGCheck - 1
          End If
        Next IGCheck
        ' If you really want the last IG on the row
        ' better to search backwards.
        For IGCheck = LastCol1 To 1 Step -1
          If .Cells(Rowtosave, IGCheck).Value = "IG" Then
            lastEG = IGCheck - 1
            Exit For
          End If
        Next IGCheck
      End If
      ' I assume there is only one row with Name in column A
      ' so there is no point in searching further.
      Exit For
    Next RowCheck

    If Rowtosave = 0 Then
      Call MsgBox("Name row not found", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If
    If lastEG = 0 Then
      Call MsgBox("EG not found on Name row", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If

    'Look for temp
    totalvalue = 0
    tempRow1 = 0          ' Initialise in case not found
    tempcol = 0
    For RowCheck = 1 To LastRow1
      If .Cells(RowCheck, 1).Value = "temp" Then
        For tempCheck = 1 To lastEG
          tempRow1 = RowCheck
          ' I assume .Cells(tempRow1, tempCheck).Value is numeric.
          ' If so "0" has to be converted to numeric for every test.
          ' Better: If .Cells(tempRow1, tempCheck).Value = 0 Then
          ' I might use "With .Cells(tempRow1, tempCheck)" because you
          ' test its value then use the value.  However, this code
          ' makes no sense to me.
          If .Cells(tempRow1, tempCheck).Value = "0" Then
            ' Why are you saving tempcol?
            tempcol = tempCheck
            ' Why are you selecting valuestoadd?
            ' You have not activated the sheet.  You cannot select a
            ' a cell except within the active worksheet.
            'valuestoadd = .Cells(tempRow1, tempcol).Select
            ' Why are you totalling all the cells with a value of zero.
            totalvalue = totalvalue + .Cells(tempRow1, tempcol).Value
          End If
        Next tempCheck
        ' I assume there is only one temp row
        Exit For
      End If
    Next RowCheck

    ' This loop appears to be searching for a empty cell
    ' in which to place totalvalue.

    'Look for empty column
    emptycol = 1
    Do
      ' Why are you selecting the cell?
      Set empty1 = .Cells(tempRow1, emptycol)
      If empty1 = "" Then
        ' Why are you place the value in the cell after the empty one?
        emptycol = emptycol + 1
        ' How will you use Colempty?
        Colempty = emptycol
        ' You cannot set a range to a numeric.
        'empty1 = totalvalue
        ' "empty1.Value = totalvalue" would be OK
        .Cells(tempRow1, emptycol).Value = totalvalue
        ' I have moved the Exit Do to inside the If.
        ' Before "emptycol = emptycol + 1" could not be reached
        Exit Do
      End If
      emptycol = emptycol + 1
    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

**New section in response to user1204868's questions and new explanation**

I started answering your questions but I am unable to reconcile all the information you have given.  The code, the explanation and the questions are not consistent.  The following is my attempt to create a consistent description.

- There is a row with "Name" in column A.  Call this the Name row.
- Within the Name row, there are cells containing "EG".  A few cells after a cell containg "EG" is a cell containing "IG".  Call an range starting at a cell containing "EG" and continuing to (but not including) the next cell containing "IG", an EG range.  In the example, the EG ranges are B:D and H:J.
- There is a row with "temp" in column A.  Call this the Temp row.  In the example, the Temp row is immediately under the Name row but apparently this is not a requirement.  The Name and Temp rows can appear anywhere within the Sheet and in either sequence.
- There is a row with "test1" in column A.  Call this the Test1 row.
- In the example, the Test1 Row is immediately under the Temp row.  The code does not access the Test1 row.  The explanation says that the row under the Temp row is the Test1 row but this is not checked.
- Within each EG range within the Temp row, there is a cell containing zero.  The cell below the zero will be empty or contain a number.  The value of those numbers for all EG ranges is to be totalled.  This total is to be saved in the cell after the first empty cell within the Temp row overwritten any existing value.  In the example, the first empty cell in the Temp row is in column N so the total will be saved in column O overwriting the existing zero.

I doubt this explanation is completely correct.  You should copy this explanation to your question and correct it so that Tim or I or someone else can understand what you really want.

Your question about the Name row not being row 1 suggests that you are concerned that as you develop the worksheet, the Name row may move down.  You need to decide what about the worksheet is fixed and what may change.  For example, must the Test1 row be immediately under the Temp row?

What are the rows with "test2" and "test3" in column A.  Are they related to the Test1 row?

**Comments on code from testing1.xlsm**

**Issue 1**

You have removed my `Option Explicit` so you have undeclared variables.

Add:

```
Dim totalvalue1 As Long
Dim totalvalue2 As Long
```

**Issue 2**

```
.Cells(LastRow1, 1).Select
```

You can only select a cell within the active worksheet.  We are accessing worksheet Sheet1 using `With` so it does not have to be active.

There is no need to select this cell so delete this statement.

**Issue 3**

```
  End If
  ' I assume there is only one row with Name in column A
  ' so there is no point in searching further.
  Exit For
Next RowCheck
```

As explained in my comment, this block must be replaced with:

```
    Exit For
  End If
Next RowCheck
```

**Issue 4**

```
For IGCheck = 1 To LastCol1
  If .Cells(Rowtosave, IGCheck).Value = "IG" Then
    lastEG = IGCheck - 1
    Exit For
  ElseIf .Cells(Rowtosave, IGCheck).Value = "EG" Then
    lastEG = IGCheck - 1
    'Exit For
  ElseIf .Cells(Rowtosave, IGCheck).Value = "CG" Then
    lastEG = IGCheck - 1
    'Exit For
  End If
Next IGCheck
```

I guess from this code and you explanations that you are searching the Name row for a range of columns which start with a cell containing "EG" and end one column before:

- the next column with a cell containing "CG" or
- the next column with a cell containing "EG" or
- the next column with a cell containing "IG"

I also guess that you have commented out the `Exit For` statements because this code does not work.

Your problem is `For IGCheck = 1 To LastCol1`.  You are starting the search at column 1 so you find the first "EG" again.

Replace this block of code with:

```
If firstEG = 0 Then
  Call MsgBox("EG not found on Name row", vbOKOnly)
  Exit Sub
End If
For IGCheck = firstEG + 1 To LastCol1
  If .Cells(Rowtosave, IGCheck).Value = "IG" Or _
     .Cells(Rowtosave, IGCheck).Value = "EG" Or _
     .Cells(Rowtosave, IGCheck).Value = "CG" Then
    lastEG = IGCheck - 1
    Exit For
  End If
Next IGCheck
```

**Issue 5**

```
If lastEG = 0 Then
  Call MsgBox("EG not found on Name row", vbOKOnly)
  Exit Sub
End If
```

The code discussed under the previous issue reveals that an EG range can be ended by the next EG.  This suggests that the final EG range could be ended by the end of the used range.

Replace this block of code with:

```
If lastEG = 0 Then
  lastEG = LastCol1 - 1
End If
```

**Issue 6**

```
For n = 1 To LastRow1
 :
Next
```

The whole of the second block of code is surrounded by this `For Loop`.  With your example data, this is the equivalent of `For n = 1 to 5`.  Within this block of code, you look for the row (RowCheck=3) with column A containing the value "temp".  You then access data from row RowCheck+n.  That is, you acess rows 4 to 8.  Is this really what you want to do?

**Issue 7**

```
For tempCheck = 1 To lastEG
```

I think this should be:

```
For tempCheck = firstEG To lastEG
```

**Issue 8**

The second block of code is a muddle.  I can see what the code does but I do not undertand why so it is difficult for me to comment.  But I will try.

The loop looking for the Temp row needs to be on the outside so something like:

```
For RowCheck = 1 To LastRow1
  If .Cells(RowCheck, 1).Value = "temp" Then

     ' Set up new headers on Name row
     ' Process all the test rows

     Exit For
  End If
Next
```

The code places an "EG" on the row above the Temp row.  This assumes the row above the Temp row is the Name row.  Either:

- The Temp row is always going to be the row below the Name row in which case you do not need to search for the Temp row or
- you should place the "EG" on row Rowtosave.

Whichever, you only need to do it once.

You should not attempt to process the rows with "testN" in column A with `For n = 1 To LastRow1`.  Choices include:

- You have made LastRow1 two less than the true last row.  Remove the `- 2` from the statement initialising LastRow1.  Replace `For n = 1 To LastRow1` with `For n = 1 To LastRow1 - tempRow1`
- Replace `For n = 1 To LastRow1`  ... `Next` with a Do Loop that continues until column A is empty or does not contain "testN" or whatever terminates this table.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply! the for "EG", it is grouped from Column B to D, that is why there is a firstEG and LastEG. Hope that clear up the doubt. I think there are alot of questions on my code. I have add in a follow up to my question. I hope you can understand what i'm trying to do and from there, maybe you can give me some opinion what have i done wrongly.. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, tony, i have solved the problem.. but i'm facing another problem which is, if i were to use the totalvalue = totalvalue + something, i may end up with alot of different types of totalvalue as I have to tabulate through out the rows, what do you sugguest?

Comment: I realized one problem, which is, if Name does not happen on the first row,for example, happens on second row, the message name not found will be shown.. i wonder why? If you know why, please let me know.

Comment: I have added a new section to my answer.  I have answered one of your new questions but the information you give is inconsistent.  Please address the issues in my new section.

Comment: can i say, since the code are as follows ` For RowCheck = 1 To LastRow1` and ` If .Cells(RowCheck, 1).Value = "Name" Then`, it should be able to check even if "Name" is not on the first row of the sheet? If not, then what is the purpose of the for loop.. And i will try and revise my question, sorry for any inconvenience...

Comment: With my code the Name row can be anywhere; it is not restricted to row 1.  I do not understand your problem.

Comment: i made some minor adjustments to your code so that i can do a summation.. but for some reason when i added in another row above name, the message "name" not found was displayed... I have uploaded one random example with the code, maybe u can help me see what's wrong with it. Link is as follow: http://www.mediafire.com/?6kvxemf2qh3kmyk

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake.  `End If` `Exit For` `Next RowCheck` should be `Exit For` `End If` `Next RowCheck`.  That is, only exit the For loop if "Name" has been found.

Comment: ok.. i will give it a try tomorrow morning.. hopefully this case can be closed by then! Thanks alot! Appreciate it!

Comment: hi, was wondering if you have tried running my code that i linked u on comment yesterday, there was a weird problem i encountered. The problem was that it actually continues to count even when the last row has reached and so giving me a total of 0 after the last row.

Comment: I have now tried your code. I have added another section to my answer discussing some of the issues I have with your code. The reason the code does not stop at the final row is included.

Comment: hi, I have fixed all the issues that u have provided and i tried using the for loop with the - temprow1, still the same result with the number of zeros. I also tried using a Do loop, no results was displayed. I think i should stick to for loop. But seriously, not sure why the zeros keep displaying when the lastrow is already found.

Comment: to add on to the comment i posted hours ago, i have tried adding - 6 to the statement `LastRow1 = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row` it works.. but i'm not sure if it will always work. I have tried a few examples, it works for now... But i'm still curious why LastRow1 doesnt equates to the last row with values?

Comment: Can you post your file again so I can look at the latest code?  Alternatively, you could email it to "TonyDallimore23 at gmail.com"

Comment: Hi, I have drop u a mail.. do have a look at it.. Thanks!